# Permitting array of hashes rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, strong-parameters

My rails version is 5 and I have request param like this,

```
{ "segment": {
    "name": "test",
    "new_filters": [
      {"criteria": "sad",
        "other_keys": [{"key": "value"}]
      }, 
      {"criteria": "sad",
        "other_keys1": [{"key1": "value1"}]
      }]
}
}
```

I am stuck in permitting the new_filter params in rails controller, 
I am trying below code,

```
params.require(:segment).permit(:name, :people_count, new_filters: [])
```

and still getting the error. But this is not the case while having array of strings in new_filter key.
Eg: ["sad", "asdasd"]. How to get the nested structure as whitelisted attribute?

Comment: try `.permit(..., new_filters: [:criteria, other_keys: [:key1])`. Your second `new_filter` has `other_keys1`, is that going to be changing ?, are you expecting any value there ?, or do you always know what keys will come there ?.

Comment: What are you doing with those params? Are you using them for mass assignment? Or something else?

Comment: `permit` can take a block as well to handling nesting but we would need to understand what you are doing with this as mentioned by @jvillian

Comment: @fanta, That seems to be working, But It's showing unpermitted params for the inner keys. The keys are expected keys only, But the nested level is too deep in my case.

Comment: You should permit all of them, add them to your permit structure, otherwise they won't pass. That's best than doing `permit!`, `permit!` is dangerous since it'll permit everything the user sends.

Comment: @jvillian, I am just storing the values in jsonb column as that is complex filter data with multiple conditions and blocks like http://ransack-demo.herokuapp.com/users/advanced_search

Comment: I guess I would ask whether you need to use strong parameters in your context. As you know, strong parameters are a safety measure associated with mass assignment. Once in a while, it is worth asking whether you really have a hammer and driving a nail is really what you're up to.

Comment: well, if it's going to be saved in a jsonb column, then I guess you don't need to permit every single key. In this case build you permitted attributes in different parts, the first one with the known keys: `.permit(:name, :people_count...)` then the unknown keys `params.require(:segment).fetch(:new_filters, {}).permit!`, and then just merge those two things and you'll get all the params you need.

Comment: I wonder if this works: `params.require(:segment).permit(:name, :people_count, new_filters: {})`. Try it and let me know. It looks like it's possible thanks to https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/e86524c0c5a26ceec92895c830d1355ae47a7034

Comment: No, It didn't work

Comment: I did this `params.require(:segment).slice(:name, :new_filters).permit!`

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me when testing with your attributes:

```
params.require(:segment).permit(:name, :people_count, new_filters: [:criteria, other_keys: [:key], other_keys1: [:key1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

In your model file for segment try adding the line

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :new_filters
```

this should allow you to pass those attributes.

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html